# no for loops allowed for this compound interest program

Tags: java

```
     public static void main(String[] args)
  { 
     //Enter savings amount
     String savingsAmountString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
      " Enter savings amount");
    //Convert string to double
    double savingsAmount = Double.parseDouble(savingsAmountString);

   //enter interest
    String interestRateString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
    "Enter annual interest rate ");
   //Convert String to double
   double annualInterestRate = Double.parseDouble(interestRateString);


   //Enter number of months
   String numberOfMonthsString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
  "Enter number of months");
  //Convert string to double
   double numberofMonths = Double.parseDouble(numberOfMonthsString);


 //obtain monthly interest rate

  double newBalance = savingsAmount * Math.pow((1+annualInterestRate/12),  (numberofMonths*12)-1)/annualInterestRate);

 String output = "after monts the result is" + newBalance; 

  JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, output);
```

this is the problem i have: Suppose you save $100 each month into a savings account with an annual interest rate of 5%. The monthly interest rate is:

0.05/12 = 0.00417 Divide the annual rate by 12.

After the first month, the value in the account is:

100 * (1 + 0.00417) = 100.417 
After the second month, the value in the account is:

(100 + 100.417) * (1 + 0.00417) = 201.252
Write a program that uses a dialog box to prompt the user to enter the monthly savings amount, and the annual percentage rate the account accrues. Use a dialog box to display the value of the account after the 6th month.

My problem originates from the formula. I cant get it to run, I understand the formula for compound interest. I wonder if Im nesting incorrectly. I have tried switching commas, and paranthesis to different places. But i still cant run it. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The idea of Stack Overflow is that we help with *specific* programming problems. An open-ended "Here's my problem, with this constraint, how would you do this" isn't particularly specific. Stack Overflow isn't meant to replace your brain. Why not spend a little bit thinking of your own ideas, implementing them, and if they don't work *then* come and ask a question?  You'll learn more both by making mistakes and having other people suggesting ideas than just the latter.

Comment: *"But i dont think my professor would count that since we havent talked about loops yet."*  - The fact that your professor hasn't taught you something doesn't mean you can't use it!  Unless you live in the DRK, initiative and self-driven learning are things that should be *encouraged* by your teachers.

Comment: I have spent 6 hours trying to make this work, I have tried using increment operators, and Math.pow which is the onlything im allowed to use on this excercise, unfortunatley if one parenthesis sign is not in the right place, it errors out and my frustration is growing. I appreciate your constructive criticism.

Comment: Well, if you have tried things, *show them*. You'll get better answers if we can see what you tried. You may have been on the right track, for all we know. And parentheses mismatch should be something your IDE helps with.

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not exactly sure what your professor asks you to do. But I find the way you derive the monthly interest rate from the annual rate unconvincing. While it is true that the annual rate tells you what amount of interest you've acquired after 12 months, that doesn't mean that you can just divide the rate by 12 to get the monthly rate because of [compound interest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest#Simplified_calculation).

Rather, you're looking for a monthly rate that after 12 month will give you the same amount of money as the annual rate. Thus, if you start with an amount of money *X*, the relation between annual interest rate *a* and monthly rate *m* should be like this:

[image]

If we want to solve this for *m* we first note that the amount of money *X* that we start with doesn't actually matter because it appears on both sides. So we get:

[image]

Or in Java:

```
double a = annualInterestRate / 100.0;
double m = Math.pow(1 + a, 1/12.0) - 1;
```

Now you can compute how much interest has been accumulated after *n* months with the basic formula for the [future value of the present amount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest#Simplified_calculation):

```
double futureAccountAmount = savingAccounAmount * Math.pow(1 + m, n);
```

Look, ma! No for-loop!

Comment: No, this is just completely wrong.  If a bank quotes an annual interest rate, then the monthly interest rate is exactly 1/12 of that.  You don't need the bizarre calculation given here.  It means that after one year, you earn slightly more interest than the published rate would indicate.  That's just how banks do it.

Comment: @DavidWallace I don't know why you call these calculations "bizarre". I think I have quite clearly argued what the rationale is (compound interest) and provided links to further illustrate my point.  The $100 example of the original question also indicates that compound interest is what user1066367 had in mind (see the (unfortunately wrong) calculation that follows the sentence "After the second month..."). Nowhere does the original question mention banks or whether they use this or a different practice in real life, the question is obviously an exercise.